# MLE for censored multivariate normal data?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, censoring

Suppose I have $q$ censored covariates, say $X_1, \ldots, X_q$ which are all left-censored with censoring values $\mathbf{d} = d_1, \ldots, d_q$. If I assume that the $X_i$ are from some multivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mathbf{\mu}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, how can I write down the likelihood to find a maximum likelihood estimator?

A paper that I read has this as the initial starting point of an algorithm, but their code only implements the likelihood in the specific case of $q = 3$, and I'm struggling to generalize the code. Of course if I could write down the likelihood I could write a (very inefficient) optimizer easily. So what I want to know is how to find the MLE for censored MVN data.